# Joining stream of ints to a String, typecast problems

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to join an array of ints in to a String using streams (e.g. `{1, 2, 3}` -> `"1, 2, 3"`), but I keep getting compile errors. There seems to be a problem with int/String type conversion.

The array is `int[] IntArray = {1, 2, 3, 4}`.

```
    String s1 = Arrays.stream(IntArray)
                        .map(String::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

gives a compile error:

```
Error:(20, 68) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
```

Replacing the map line with `.map(Object::toString)` or `.map(n -> Integer.toString(n))` doesn't work either:

```
Error:(23, 49) java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
method toString in class java.lang.Object cannot be applied to given types
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

for `.map(Object::toString)`, and the first error for `.map(n -> Integer.toString(n))`.

Comment: The type of the stream is `IntStream`, and thus all of the values placed into it must be `int`, which is why you get the first error (since the return from the map function is `String`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use:

```
int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
String s1 = Arrays.stream(intArray)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

There is one subtle difference here, which is **very** important:

`mapToObj(String::valueOf)`

I map the `IntStream` to a `Stream<String>` here, if you use the regular `map` method, then it only takes an `IntUnaryOperator` and thus you must stay within `int`.